# Ionic 3 with errors on first build

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've got a strange behaviour when i "serve" my ionic 3 project. Directly after serving via "ionic serve -l" I see the following errors on console:

```
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser
--lab - Ctrl+C to cancel
[10:25:11]  watch started ...
[10:25:11]  build dev started ...
[10:25:11]  clean started ...
[10:25:11]  clean finished in 6 ms
[10:25:11]  copy started ...
[10:25:12]  deeplinks started ...
[10:25:12]  deeplinks finished in 67 ms
[10:25:12]  transpile started ...
[10:25:16]  typescript: src/app/app.component.ts, line: 25
            Type '({ title: string; component: typeof EventsPage; icon: string; } | { title: string; component: typ...'
            is not assignable to type '{ title: string; component: any; }[]'. Type '{ title: string; component: typeof
            EventsPage; icon: string; } | { title: string; component: type...' is not assignable to type '{ title:
            string; component: any; }'. Type '{ title: string; component: typeof EventsPage; icon: string; }' is not
            assignable to type '{ title: string; component: any; }'. Object literal may only specify known properties,
            and 'icon' does not exist in type '{ title: string; component: any; }'.

      L24:  this.pages = [
      L25:    { title: 'Events', component: EventsPage, icon: 'calendar' },
      L26:    { title: 'Merkliste', component: ListPage, icon: 'bookmark' },

[10:25:16]  typescript: src/pages/events/events.ts, line: 29
            Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

      L28:    console.log("found events in local storage");
      L29:  } else {
      L30:    console.log("no events found in local storage");

[10:25:16]  typescript: src/pages/events/events.ts, line: 37
            A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation.


[10:25:16]  typescript: src/pages/events/events.ts, line: 53
            Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

      L53:    doRefresh(refresher) {
      L54:      console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

[10:25:16]  typescript: src/pages/locations/locations.ts, line: 17
            Property 'locations' does not exist on type 'LocationsPage'.

      L16:  if(locations){
      L17:    this.locations = locations;
      L18:    console.log("found locations in local storage");

[...]some more errors here[..]

[10:25:16]  copy finished in 4.91 s
[10:25:16]  watch ready in 5.01 s
```

After doing nothing else than saving the file src/app/app.component.ts again ionic automatically starts a new build:

```
[10:28:44]  build started ...
[10:28:44]  deeplinks update started ...
[10:28:44]  deeplinks update finished in 130 ms
[10:28:44]  transpile update started ...
[10:28:44]  transpile update finished in 140 ms
[10:28:44]  webpack started ...
[10:28:56]  webpack finished in 11.90 s
[10:28:56]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[10:28:59]  sass finished in 2.87 s
[10:28:59]  build finished in 15.10 s

[10:28:59]  build started ...
[10:28:59]  deeplinks update started ...
[10:28:59]  deeplinks update finished in 43 ms
[10:28:59]  transpile update started ...
[10:28:59]  transpile update finished in 60 ms
[10:28:59]  build finished in 149 ms
```

and my project comes up without any future error.
But while working on the project the same error occures again (just from time to time after working on other files than app.component.ts) and again I have to save src/app/app.component.ts (without making any changes on the file itselt) to bring the project up again.

Any ideas why this could happend?

I'm on Ionic CLI version 3.20.0.
Here is an output of "ionic info":

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.11.3
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : macOS High Sierra

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Source of app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { EventsPage } from '../pages/events/events';
import { LocationsPage } from '../pages/locations/locations';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = EventsPage;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Events', component: EventsPage, icon: 'calendar' },
      { title: 'Merkliste', component: ListPage, icon: 'bookmark' },
      { title: 'Locations', component: LocationsPage, icon: 'home' },
      { title: 'Einloggen', component: ListPage, icon: 'log-in' }
    ];

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}
```

Source of events.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { AddItemPage } from '../add-item/add-item'
import { ItemDetailPage } from '../item-detail/item-detail';
import { EventPage } from '../event/event';
import { DataProvider } from '../../providers/data/data';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-events',
  templateUrl: 'events.html'
})
export class EventsPage {

  public events = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public dataService: DataProvider, public http: Http) {

    this.dataService.getEvents().then((events) => {

      if(events){
        this.events = events;
        console.log("found events in local storage");
      } else {
        console.log("no events found in local storage");
        this.refreshEvents();
      }

    });

  }


  refreshEvents(public http: Http) {

    console.log("refreshing events");
    this.http.get('https://www.domain.tld/api/events').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      this.events = data;
      this.dataService.saveEvents(this.events);
    });

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){

  }

  doRefresh(refresher) {
    console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);
    this.refreshEvents();

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      refresher.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }

  addEvent(){

    let addModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddItemPage);

    addModal.onDidDismiss((event) => {

          if(event){
            this.saveEvent(event);
          }

    });

    addModal.present();

  }

  saveEvent(event){
    this.events.push(event);
  }

  viewEvent(event_id){
    console.log("opening event " + event_id);
    this.navCtrl.push(EventPage, {
      event_id: event_id
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: It will be good if you share your app.component.ts and events.ts

Comment: Sure, I've just added the source of both files to my main question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'icon' does not exist in type '{ title: string; component: any; }'.
```

You can't use the value icon since it doesn't exists in that object.

Comment: Yes it does. Anyway - I can remove the value icon completly and what then happens is that Ionic crashes on another line:

`[11:54:23]  typescript: src/pages/events/events.ts, line: 29
            Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

      L28:    console.log("found events in local storage");
      L29:  } else {
      L30:    console.log("no events found in local storage");`
      
but as said before - if I now save app.component.ts again (without touching any bit of code) Ionic starts to re-build and the project comes up without any future error logged.